# LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-2.0, activeresource

I have two applications named as 'Book' and 'Inventory' respectively. My 'Book' app is running on 3000 port & 'Inventory' app is running on 4000 port. I have 'book' model in 'Book' app and 'inventory' model in 'Inventory' app. In my 'Book' app I have created inventory.rb file inside app/models folder as below

```
require 'active_resource'

class Inventory < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://localhost:4000'
end
```

In gemfile I have included :

```
gem 'activeresource'
```

When I am trying to access Inventory model from  my 'Book' app console, I am getting below error

```
2.0.0-p643 :234 >   require 'active_resource'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_resource
```

Or when I am trying

```
Invetory.last
```

I am getting the same error.

Comment: can you try putting this in gemfile `gem 'activeresource', require: 'active_resource'` in place of `gem 'activeresource'` and bundle again?

Comment: what version of rails are you using? Can you confirm that gem 'active resource' is in the book applications Gemfile.. were there any errors when bundling it?

Comment: My rails version is '4.2.4
' & I did not get any errors while bundling

Comment: @sajan I included gem 'activeresource', require: 'active_resource' instead of 'activeresource', then I bundle installed, then I tried Invetory.last so it just returned me nil, though I have records in my Inventory model & doing Inventory.count gave me error saying 'NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for FoodMaster:Class'

Comment: Do you have anything named `FoodMaster` ? I did not find anythng related to it. And can you just `Inventory` and see if returns the usual result of attribute names of model ?

Comment: @sajan its 'Inventory' actually not 'FoodMaster' : NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for Inventory:Class'

Comment: When I am requiring it in my console, its returning false : require 'active_resource'